# Drawing a graphic image with LaTeX for an e-book using Markdown

Tags: graphics, trees, markdown

How can I draw the picture below with LaTeX? I will be using it in an e-book using Markdown. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This could help you: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See <a href="http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/">minimal working example (MWE)</a> for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @susis strolch, Ok, fair enough. I know how to do equations, but I am not sure about the lines. Can you direct me to a source so that I can learn how to draw the lines? Also, one part of my question is to draw this without using any packages because I don't know if it would work with the conversion to e-book. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution using `xymatrix`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[ 
 \xymatrix@C=.5cm{
 & \mbox{Tycho}              \ar@{-}[d]              & \\ 
 & \mbox{Database } (R,T)    \ar@{-}[d]              & \\ 
 & \mbox{Kepler }\to R^3=T^2 \ar@{-}[d]              & \\
 & \mbox{Newton }\to R^3=T^2 \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[dr] & \\
 F=\displaystyle\frac{1}{R^2} & & F=\displaystyle\frac{R}{T^2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I increase the size of the image?

Comment: You can just change the font size like normal text. For example, use `{\Large ... }`

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{levelsep=1cm,nodesep=3pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{psTree}{\Tr{Tycho}}
    \begin{psTree}{\Tr{Database $(R,T)$}}
        \begin{psTree}{\Tr{Keppler  $\to R^3 = T^2$}}
            \begin{psTree}[levelsep=2cm,nodesep=5pt]{\Tr{Newton  $\to R^3 = T^2$}}
                \Tr{$\displaystyle F=\frac{1}{R^2}$}
                \Tr{$\displaystyle F=\frac{R}{T^2}$}
            \end{psTree}
        \end{psTree}
    \end{psTree}
\end{psTree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried to compile this online here http://www.compileonline.com/try_latex_online.php but it gives `! LaTeX Error: File 'standalone.cls' not found.` I just wanted to change the color of the border and play with it a little.

Comment: @Zeynel: Don't use online compiler.

Comment: ok. How can I change color of the border so that it is black?

Comment: The border is created by ImageMagick's command named `convert`.

Answer (score 0):

With Diagram.Codes Studio this can be easily done:

```
TEX"{Database } (R,T)" as a
TEX"{Kepler }\to R^3=T^2" as b
TEX"{Newton }\to R^3=T^2" as c
TEX"F=\displaystyle\frac{1}{R^2}" as d
TEX"F=\displaystyle\frac{R}{T^2}" as e

a->b
b->c
c->d,e
```

[image]